# problem string special charset hextobin php

Tags: php, utf-8, cp1252

I have 1 hex string that I want to pass to a string, but I get strange characters, why?

```
$string = "52656C6F6A204E616D69209620534B4D4549209620416375E17469636F";
$productnamehex = hex2bin($string);
```

result:

```
Reloj Nami � SKMEI � Acu�tico
```

should show:

```
Reloj Nami – SKMEI – Acuático
```

poor with `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode` but nothing seems to work.

PHP TESTER CODE:

```
<?php
$string = "52656C6F6A204E616D69209620534B4D4549209620416375E17469636F";
$productnamehex = hex2bin($string);
echo $productnamehex;
```

Comment: What makes you say it "should" show `Reloj Nami – SKMEI – Acuático`? Because the problematic character in your string uses a single byte value `96` surrounded by spaces (hex `20`), which is decimal 150, which in ASCII, ANSI, and UTF-8 is smack dab in the middle of the [C1 controls in the Latin-1 Supplement block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement) (0x0080-0x009F). There is literally no way for it to be an en-dash, because that has hex code `2013`, which is decimal value 8211. Your code is 100% doing the right thing here =)

Comment: hello go to http://phptester.net/
and use
`$string = "52656C6F6A204E616D69209620534B4D4549209620416375E17469636F";
$productnamehex = hex2bin($string);
echo $productnamehex;`

shows weird characters

Comment: Yes, they are saying that whatever gave you `52656C6F6A204E616D69209620534B4D4549209620416375E17469636F` gave it wrong. That is not `Reloj Nami – SKMEI – Acuático`. The dashes are malformed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string is encoded with MS cp1252.

The function `utf8_encode()` is misleading in that it only partially translates it because it *only* works with ISO-8859-1, of which cp1252 is a *superset* that includes additional characters like em-dashes and en-dashes, as in your string.

To properly convert the string:

```php
$hex = "52656C6F6A204E616D69209620534B4D4549209620416375E17469636F";
$cp1252 = hex2bin($hex);
$utf8 = mb_convert_encoding($cp1252, 'UTF-8', 'cp1252');

var_dump($hex, $cp1252, $utf8);
```

Output:

```
string(58) "52656C6F6A204E616D69209620534B4D4549209620416375E17469636F"
string(29) "Reloj Nami � SKMEI � Acu�tico"
string(34) "Reloj Nami – SKMEI – Acuático"
```

See also: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Be warned that text encoding is rarely ever obvious just by looking at the data, and even the functions that purport to detect the encoding are simply making *educated guesses*. If it weren't for the dashes it simply wouldn't be possible to know which encoding it was for certain.

Text encoding is important *metadata* that must be tracked alongside the data itself.

Comment: Amazing! Is there any way to replace this problematic character with the "–" to "-"

Comment: `$productnamehex = str_replace("–", "-", $productnamehex);
    $productnamehex = str_replace("&#45", "-", $productnamehex);
    $productnamehex = str_replace("&#8211", "-", $productnamehex);`

Comment: i tried that and it worked you are amazing thank you very much! is there any better way to do it? more optimal and clean?

Comment: I mean replace the "–"